# php wrapper library for google appengine access

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, objectify

We have objectify for accessing non-relational database with google appengine in java.

I was wondering if there is any similar library I can use for accessing mysql in google appengine php.

Thanks and regards
Rishabbh

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [the docs for php and cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/#PHP_Different_interfaces)?

> **Connecting from App Engine**
>
> These following examples show how to connect from a deployed App
>   Engine application using a socket or named pipe that specifies the
>   Cloud SQL instance. When you connect from App Engine, you can use the
>   root user and no password (as shown here), or you can use a specific
>   database user and password.
>
> **PDO_MySQL**
>
> ```
> $db = new pdo('mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/<your-project-id>:<your-instance-name>;dbname=<database-name>',
>   'root',  // username
>   ''       // password
>   );
> ```
>
> **mysqli**
>
> ```
> $sql = new mysqli(null,
>   'root', // username
>   '',     // password
>   <database-name>,
>   null,
>   '/cloudsql/<your-project-id>:<your-instance-name>'
>   );
> ```
>
> **MySQL API**
>
> ```
> $conn = mysql_connect(':/cloudsql/<your-project-id>:<your-instance-name>',
>   'root', // username
>   ''      // password
>   );
> mysql_select_db('<database-name'>);
> ```

Comment: Thanks Josh for your response.. 

Yeah i went thru these but these are normal api's from php libraries. I was wondering if there was something other than this available.

Comment: @ridua you can also use Doctrine as an ORM since it uses native php mysql libraries on the back end.

Answer (score 1):

If you want non-relational data, then Datastore is what you want (rather than MySQL). It has a free tier and can be accessed using this library

https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds

(disclaimer: I am the author)

Comment: Hi Tom  

Thanks for your response..

i wish to go with relational database because we have a lot of analytics that would go in and we would need features like grouping etc which as i understand is not possible with datastore.

An example of my requirement can be average standard deviation for a given students in marks scored.

As i understand, with non-relational db, we'd have to pull in the data into app and then calculate all stats (Please correct me if i am wrong)